# Warning msg in R (4.22) when using dada2 filterandtrim function: 'some input samples had no reads pass the filter'

Tags: r

I downloaded fastq files from https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/view/PRJNA856085 and then loaded them into R to use. While following the dada2 pipeline tutorial by benjjneb 1.16 I encountered an issue when trying to filter and trim.

This is the warning msg i get:

`out <- filterAndTrim(fnTFs, filtFs, fnTRs, filtRs, truncLen=c(230,220), maxN=0, maxEE=c(2,5), truncQ=2, rm.phix=TRUE, minLen=175, compress=TRUE, multithread=TRUE) Creating output directory: /home/marina/Squid_Practice/Extra_Datasets/Dwarf_form/UnzippedD/filtered warning: Some input samples had no reads pass the filter.`

If i ignore the warning and keep going only 0.04% of my reads pass filtering.

When I go and look in my filter and trimmed folders i notice that two of the fastaq files are missing from the filterd folder but are present in the trimmed one, more specifically the SRR20006231_1.fastq.gz SRR20006231_2.fastq.gz and SRR20006256_1.fastq.gz SRR20006256_2.fastq.gz

However, I am not sure how to fix this or even why it is occurring, I would be grateful for any suggestions thank you!

*Edit* Someone kindly mentioned I should post more of my code and packages used :)

```
options(echo=TRUE) # Enables output when running the code as Rscript

library("dada2") 
library("phyloseq") 
library("magrittr")

path <- getwd() # Setting path as the location of the script
print(paste("Executing DADA2 processing script in:", path))

# This script assumes the file input name is something like 
# Sample1_S001_1.fastq.gz and Sample1_S001_2.fastq.gz
fnFs <- sort(list.files(path, pattern="_1.fastq.gz", full.names = TRUE))
fnRs <- sort(list.files(path, pattern="_2.fastq.gz", full.names = TRUE))

print("Cutadapt preprocessing to remove F&R primer sequences")
dir.create(file.path("trimmed"), showWarnings = TRUE) 
# Make "trimmed" folder for trimmed output

# This invokes the external python programme cutadapt

#cutadapt -g GTGCCAGCMGCCGCGG-G GGACTACHVGGGTWTCTAAT\

FWD <- "GTGCCAGCMGCCGCGG" 
REV <- "GGACTACHVGGGTWTCTAAT"
FWD.RC <- rc(FWD)
REV.RC <- rc(REV)
R1.flag <- paste("-g", FWD, "-a", REV.RC)
R2.flag <- paste("-G", REV, "-A", FWD.RC)

fnFs.cut <- file.path("trimmed", basename(fnFs))
fnRs.cut <- file.path("trimmed", basename(fnRs))

for(i in 1:length(fnFs)){
  system2("/home/envs/cutadaptenv/bin/cutadapt", 
c(R1.flag, R2.flag, "-n", 2, "-j", 0, "-o",
                                                                     
fnFs.cut[i], "-p", fnRs.cut[i],
                                                                     
paste0('"', fnFs[i], '"'),
                                                                     
paste0('"', fnRs[i], '"')))
}


print("Completed preprocessing!")


# '[' = R accessor for sapply
# The reason for the parsing here is for:
# Sample1_S001_1.fastq.gz --> Sample1_S001 for duplicated sample name

# This takes first and second part of file name separated by "_"
sample_names <-  basename(fnFs) %>% strsplit("_") %>%
  sapply(`[`, c(1,2)) %>% apply(2,paste,collapse="_")


filt_path <- file.path(path, "filtered") 


# Generates file path of trimmed files for input to filtering
fnTFs <- sort(list.files(paste0(path,"/trimmed"), pattern="_1.fastq.gz", full.names= TRUE))
fnTRs <- sort(list.files(paste0(path,"/trimmed"), pattern="_2.fastq.gz", full.names= TRUE))

# Output file names for after filtering
filtFs <- file.path(filt_path, paste0(sample_names, "_F_filt.fastq.gz"))
filtRs <- file.path(filt_path, paste0(sample_names, "_R_filt.fastq.gz"))

names(filtFs) <- sample_names
names(filtRs) <- sample_names


# DADA2 pipeline - uses 240,200 <-- will test

#230,220 - after filterAndTrim (69.16), after complete run 63.84% 
#240,200 - after filterAndTrim (68.07%), after complete run 62.56%


# On Windows set multithread=FALSE

out <- filterAndTrim(fnTFs, filtFs, fnTRs, filtRs, truncLen=c(230,220),
                     maxN=0, maxEE=c(2,5), truncQ=2, rm.phix=TRUE, minLen=175, compress=TRUE, multithread=TRUE)

head(out)


# You assess your processing by the output here:
print(paste0(round(sum(out[,2] / out[,1])/nrow(out) * 100, digits=2), "% of reads passed filtering"))

print("Based on a rule of thumb, proceed only if the majority (>50%) of reads passed filtering.")`
```

Comment: No information on what packages are being assumed to be  installed and loaded. Are you really expecting us to go out and search for this function? And then to construct the code you used to read those files? Think again.

Comment: @IRTFM thank you for your comment, I've now added my code and packages. Please let me know if I should add anything else :)

Comment: Files are still on the web.Voting to close as lacking necessary info to support debugging efforts. Here's the text that will  label your Q if you do not supply what's needed: "**Needs debugging details** \n 
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." Here's the link to the first one. `ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR200/031/SRR20006231/SRR20006231_1.fastq.gz` You should do the work of constructing code to either read directly from the web links or  downloads and then reads locally